# How to compare two cells in excel and output the matched cell content in specific format?

Tags: microsoft-excel, comparison

I need a formula that can do the following:

1. compare cell A2 with All of column B
2. if found multiple matches, then copy matched results that contains contents of cell A2 and output it in Cell D in specific format (need the matched results to be separated by "|/" in between every file names). also need the check to keep looking in column B until no more matched content of cell A2 is found in column B.

For example:

- P/N to look in column B is: DD0110LXSC-DRY
- Columns to look for is all of column B.
- The formula starts looking at B1; since content contains "DD0110LXSC-DRY", copy "DD0110LXSC-DRY_01.jpg" to cell D2.
- Keep comparing DD0110LXSC-DRY to cell B3 and the following cells below until no more "DD0110LXSC-DRY" is in any of the cells content.

Sample:

```
(A)             (B)                     (C)
P/N             File Name               formula
DD0110LXSC-DRY  DD0110LXSC-DRY_01.jpg   DD0110LXSC-DRY_01.jpg|/DD0110LXSC-DRY_02.jpg|/ DD0110LXSC-DRY_03.jpg|/ DD0110LXSC-DRY_04.jpg|/ DD0110LXSC-DRY_05.jpg|/ DD0110LXSC-DRY_06.jpg
                DD0110LXSC-DRY_02.jpg       
                DD0110LXSC-DRY_03.jpg       
                DD0110LXSC-DRY_04.jpg       
                DD0110LXSC-DRY_05.jpg       
                DD0110LXSC-DRY_06.jpg       
DD0204BMWMC     DD0204BMWMC_02.jpg
```

formula for column C:

```
= concatenate(B2,"|/",B3,"|/",B4,"|/",B5,"|/",B6,"|/",B7)
```

Comment: Are all of the matching filenames grouped together with the part number or are they scattered throughout and you need to search all of Column B to find any where they exist?

Comment: Hi Fixer1234

They are already grouped. I just copy the file names from windows explorer as path (it's already sorted by name).

Answer (score 0):

Select the row or column that you want to find then copy it.
Press **ctrl+F** and paste the row/column that you select.
Highlight the column that you want to look then click **Find All**.

If you want to narrow your search, you can choose **option** under ctrl+F.

Comment: You might have misread the question.  It isn't about copying.  The objective is to find all of the filenames that contain the part number in (each filled cell in) column A and concatenate them in column C in the same row as the part number.  Also implied, do it automatically rather than manually.

Comment: Thank you Zeleena. I thought of your method already but that's only good for few items. I have thousands of P/Ns. I was looking for of a formula where i can just drag and drop the same formula into every part number instead of click select P/n, CTRL C, CTRL F, past P/N, enter, select that cell, CTRL V to the cell.

Hope you understand what i'm trying to do :)

Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

According your example: your data is like a pivot table output and you need to check for matches only until next entry in the first column (and all those are matches), not in the whole second column.

My answer is solution for the above mentioned scenario, if your data isn't sorted in that way than you either need to use complex array formulas, either VBA.

[image]

Solution:

- at first you need to fill all the empty cells in first column (guidance is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762340/fill-non-contiguous-blank-cells-with-the-value-from-the-cell-above-the-first-bla))
- formula in column C: `=IF(A2=A1,C1&"|/","")&B2`
- and you need a helper column in column D: `=A2<>A3`, this will give you whether actual row is the last one of the same P/N, just filter for it (TRUE) and you'll get your desired output.

Comment: Thank you Mate Juhasz. However, i also need this data on another sheet.

lets Sheet 2 in my excel workbook contains the contents above image. However, in sheet 1, say i have the following columns

P/N                           |       Main Image                   |    Gallery

DD0110LXSC-DRY   | DD0110LXSC-DRY_01.jpg |  DD0110LXSC-DRY_02.jpg|/DD0110LXSC-DRY_03.jpg|/DD0110LXSC-DRY_04.jpg|/DD0110LXSC-DRY_05.jpg|/DD0110LXSC-DRY_06.jpg

How do i compare the P/N in sheet 1 matches the P/N in sheet 2 and only copy the content of that has all the file names - in this case C7?

Thank you

Comment: @shenlong81: Please update your question with the new requirements and I'll also update the answer.